# why my question have star?

Tags: support

Is putting a star contrast with close vote?

[How to deal with people in academia that have anti-science or opposing views from mainstream science?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/114264/how-to-deal-with-people-in-academia-that-have-anti-science-or-opposing-views-fro?noredirect=1#comment299720_114264)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a little confused ...

The only star I am aware of if the one below the downvote arrow. This star is used to favorite a question. The linked question is currently a favorite of 3 people. You only need 97 more and then you will get a [stellar question badge](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question). Beyond a way to earn badges, favorites also show up in your profile. For example, you have marked 17 questions as your favorites: 
https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/41198/ssimon?tab=favorites so you seem to be familiar with the concept. There was a slight site redesign recently, so maybe the new look confused you.

The star has nothing to do with down votes or votes to close.

Comment: ohh!! yes, when the website change? It is such a quick design change